# How to use getdate syntax on existing code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to edit my code in order that some of it will run on yesterday data and some of it will run on today data (using `getdate()` or any other date function.)

My code is:

```
(CAST(vw_public_task.complete_date AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00' and '23:59' 
 or 
 CAST(vw_public_task.complete_date AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00' and '08:00')
```

I wish that `CAST(vw_public_task.complete_date AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00' and '23:59'` will run on yesterday data and `CAST(vw_public_task.complete_date AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00' and '08:00'` on today data.

I tried to edit it with `getdate()` and other dates functions without success.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try DATEDIFF() function?

Comment: yes...  but I cause me to some issues, how can I combine both of them ?

Comment: So, you want to ignore anything that happens *during* the last minute of yesterday? This is usually why it's better to avoid `BETWEEN` and use `<` and *exclusive* endpoints for periods - they're easier to reason about and don't depend on the current precision of the data type.

Comment: its correct... but the data I'm locking forward is: searching for all completed date that occur during last day  from 08:00am till current day 08:00am (it should give same results and not be depended on execute time).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting your column to time (thus loosing the option to test it's date part, or to use any indexes you might have on this column), you can get yesterday's 08:00 and today's 08:00 using double `cast` and `dateadd` on `getdate`:

This will get you today's 08:00:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() As date) As datetime))
```

and this will get you yesterday's 08:00:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, -16, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() As date) As datetime))
```

So your where clause can be something like this:

```
WHERE vw_public_task.complete_date <=
      DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() As date) As datetime))
AND vw_public_task.complete_date >= 
      DATEADD(HOUR, -16, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() As date) As datetime))
```

Comment: Hi and thank for your respond, after I execute it I'm still getting results from today date after 08:00am ( I want to retrieve data till current execute date 08:00am and not after it.)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] with DDL + DML for sample data and the complete query. It's very hard to debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variable.

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME = 
                        DATEADD(HOUR, 8,  
                        DATEADD(DAY, DAY(GETDATE()) - 2 ,  
                        DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1,  
                        DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1900, 0)))) -- 2016-07-31 08:00:00.000

DECLARE @Today DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @YesterDay) -- 2016-08-01 08:00:00.000
```

Where clause looks like:

```
WHERE 
    vw_public_task.complete_date <= @Today AND
    vw_public_task.complete_date >=  @Yesterday
```

Comment: Hi, how the syntax should be look like at the end? I added "DECLARE"data that you sent at the end of my query and than I pasted the second code you sent me but it failed for my, probably I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Coldfire `DECLARE` must be at the top then query. Try this please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
WHERE
    vw_public_task.complete_date >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000102',GETDATE()),
                     '1900-01-01T08:00:00') and
    vw_public_task.complete_date < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',GETDATE()),
                     '1900-01-01T08:00:00')
```

My `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pairs may look a little funky, but you can hopefully work out what they're doing. Once you realise that `DATEDIFF` only works in terms of *transitions*, and returns an `int`, you'll see that the inner `DATEDIFF` expressions are computing how many (whole) days have elapsed since 1st/2nd of January 1900.

We're then adding that number of days onto 08:00 on the 1st of January 1900. Which for the second expression means that we compute 08:00 today. For the first expression, since we first counted the whole number of days since the *2nd*, but then add that onto 08:00 on the 1st, it means we're computing 08:00 yesterday.

Comment: Is `DateAdd/DateDiff` better then `cast(@datetime cast(as date) as datetime`)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - it allows you to be "cute" - such as here where we get the time offset applied as part of a single calculation rather than getting midnight and then having to adjust further. Also cuteness in being able to calculate "yesterday", "last day of the month" and other such "special" dates using the same pattern.

Comment: Yeah, but that I can do with using `dateadd` like in my answer. I was hoping you could say if any of them is better performance-wise. IMHO, double casting is more readable, but if there is a performance hit comparing to the dateadd/datediff method then obviously your answer is better.